# How does python3 diamond inheritance works for data fields? How to initialize the inherited fields with super()._init__?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I was checking this problem to understand multiple inheritance and I got stuck.
How can I set the fields of the inherited objects from the last class?

```
class Vehicle():
  def __init__(self, name:str, seats:int):
    self.name = name
    self.seats = seats

  def print_vehicle(self):
    print(f'Vehicle {self.name} has {self.seats} seats')

class Boat(Vehicle):
  def __init__(self, name:str, seats:int, engine_type:str):
    super().__init__(name, seats)
    self.engine_type = engine_type

  def print_vehicle(self):
    print(f'Boat {self.name} has {self.seats} seats and engine {self.engine_type}')

class Car(Vehicle):
  def __init__(self, name:str, seats:int, fuel:str):
    super().__init__(name, seats)
    self.fuel = fuel

  def print_vehicle(self):
    print(f'Car {self.name} has fuel {self.fuel}')

class AnphibiousCar(Boat, Car):
  def __init__(self, name, seats, engine_type, fuel):
    super(AnphibiousCar, self).__init__(name, seats, engine_type) # ???
    
  def print_vehicle(self):
    print(f'Anphibious car {self.name} has {self.seats} seats and {self.engine_type} - {self.fuel} engine')
    
ac = AnphibiousCar('name', 4, 'piston', 'gas')
ac.print_vehicle()
```

Comment: Instance attributes are not part of the class definition, so they aren't affected by inheritance. They are simply defined and redefined as the *methods* are called in the order specified by the method resolution order.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that each class should focus **only** on the stuff which is its direct responsibility; the rest should be **delegated** to *superclasses* (and *note* that, when you deal with such a *cooperative inheritance* with `super()`, your methods that call `super()` *should not need to know* what exactly are the actual *superclasses*, in particular the nearest one - as this can change, depending on the actual class of `self`).

So let's reimplement your classes (with a bunch of explanations in the comments):

```
class Vehicle:

    # Added the `*,` marker to make `name` and `seats` *keyword-only*
    # arguments (i.e., arguments that are identified only by their
    # *names*, never by their positions in a call's arguments list).
    def __init__(self, *, name: str, seats: int):
        self.name = name
        self.seats = seats

    # We abstract out class-specific features into separate methods,
    # keeping in the `print_vehicle()` method only the common stuff,
    # so that in subclasses we'll need to customize only those methods
    # (`list_features()`, `get_type_label()`), *not* `print_vehicle()`.
    def print_vehicle(self):
        vehicle_type_label = self.get_type_label()
        features = ', '.join(self.list_features())
        print(f'{vehicle_type_label} {self.name}: {features}.')

    # Side note: the `list[str]` type annotation requires Python 3.9
    # or newer (for compatibility with older versions you need to
    # replace it with `List[str]`, using `from typing import List`).
    def list_features(self) -> list[str]:
        return [f'has {self.seats} seats']

    # This implementation is, in fact, quite generic (so that
    # in most subclasses we will *not* need to customize it).
    def get_type_label(self) -> str:
        return self.__class__.__name__


class Boat(Vehicle):

    # Only `Boat`-specific arguments (as keyword-only ones, as above...)
    # are declared here explicitly. Any other are treated as a "black
    # box", just being passed into superclasses...
    def __init__(self, *, engine_type: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.engine_type = engine_type

    # Also here we focus only on this-class-specific stuff, handling
    # other stuff as "agnostically" as possible...
    def list_features(self) -> list[str]:
        return super().list_features() + [f'has {self.engine_type} engine']


class Car(Vehicle):

    # And analogously...
    def __init__(self, *, fuel: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fuel = fuel

    def list_features(self) -> list[str]:
        return super().list_features() + [f'needs {self.fuel} fuel']


class AmphibiousCar(Boat, Car):

    # Note: here we get our `__init__()` and `list_features()`
    # for free (!), as the superclasses provide all we need
    # when it comes to those two methods.

    # The only thing we may want to customize is:
    def get_type_label(self) -> str:
        return 'Amphibious car'


ac = AmphibiousCar(
    name='Julia-III',
    seats=4,
    engine_type='piston',
    fuel='gas')

# "Amphibious car Julia-III: has 4 seats, needs gas fuel, has piston engine."
ac.print_vehicle()
```

As a further reading, I'd recommend: https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors:

- `super(AnphibiousCar, self).__init__(name, seats, engine_type)` could become
  `Boat.__init__(self, name, seats, engine_type)` so calling the class you could
  give information about how to initialize it.
- there is a missing parameter in `Boat` where you should give a `fuel` argument
  to the superclass `Vehicle`, like `super().__init__(name, seats, "oil")`

As you can note if you use `super` you don't need to pass `self`, if you use
the class name you are using it.

My point of view is that, yes, is good to understand, but don't loose to much
time as this kind of multiple inheritance is only theoretical and practically
not used in real coding. This in fact can cause a lot of confusion and add
boilerplate... "new" languages like, for example, Rust do not even provide
inheritance.
Just to say: "Yes, study it, but keep it simple" ^_^